# How to set initial state in native HTML popover to open with plain HTML

Tags: html

I'm quite excited about the new native popover attribute.

What I'm still struggling with in my tests is setting the initial state of the popover to open without JavaScript.

The spec apparently can be found here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/popover.html

But I was not able to find documentation about how to set the initial state. My test-use-case would be to set an unobtrusive toggleable cookie banner that would be initially open (based on what the server says if cookies are accepted or not). I'm trying to get it working without any JavaScript.

Here's a simple example that works currently in Chrome Canary and Safari Technology Preview:

```html
<button popovertarget="mypopover">Toggle popover</button>
<div popover="manual" id="mypopover">
  <p>How to set this initially open?</p>
  <button popovertarget="mypopover">Close popover</button>
</div>
```

You can check the current status of the support for [popover from caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_popover)

To recap: How can I set the popover to be initially open without JS?

Comment: To set it to open by default, it looks like you will have to use javascript. Maybe a `<div popover="manual" id="mypopover" onload="this.showPopover()">...</div>` can work? Otherwise you should select the ID and activate it manually. At leas, thats what the spec describes. Not sure how well features Safari's implementation is atm.

Comment: Yep, it just irks me that we get these great tools and all require javascript to work fully. I mean, just having an "open" attribute there would allow us to use no js at all.

Comment: Actually, for the purposes here it works without javascript, you just want a popover to open on load, which I think is just assumed to not be proper. Popovers only popover after the page is interacted with I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do exactly the same thing, and the solution is surprisingly simple with CSS:

```
[popover] {
    display: block;
}

[popover]:popover-open {
    display: none;
}
```

As @Kaiido commented below, this will invert the JS API: `showPopover` will hide the popover and `hidePopover` will show it.

Comment: Clever trick, however it should probably be noted that now the JS API will be inverted: `showPopover` will hide the popover and `hidePopover` will show it.

Comment: Since Mikko was looking for a JS-free solution, I thought this was an acceptable trade-off. :)

Comment: It certainly might be, but others may be surprised by that, so it would be good for you to add that as a note in your answer.